# Is it possible to make dilation or erosion morphology for a Uint8ClampedArray from ImageData canvas?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, mathematical-morphology

I've got an Uint8ClampedArray from ImageData(ctx.getImageData()). I grayscaled it by 0.21 * R + 0.72 * G + 0.07 * B formula. So now I have a Uint8ClampedArray, where each 4 is a rgba channels.
I need to make dilation with that array, then with the result of dilation make an erosion. I was searching over the internet and found many different solutions with python and OpenCV, but nothing with JS. I know that SVG allows to use feMorphology filters with dilation and erosion, but is there something like that in canvas? Or is that possible to use Uint8ClampedArray | ImageData with svg filters?
Is it possible to make own algorithm, which will make these morph operations?
Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible to make your own algo. And no you can't apply an SVG filter *directly* on the `ImageData` object, but you can render it on a canvas, apply the SVG filter from it and grab a new `ImageData`. But as it stands your question is too open ended for StackOverflow format.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added an answer with a demonstration of @Kaiido's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, own algo:
Erosion:

```
function erosionFilter(frame, width, height) {
const erodedFrame = new Uint8ClampedArray(frame.length);

for (let y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {
  for (let x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
    let min = 255;

    for (let j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
      for (let i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        const value = frame[(y + j) * width + (x + i)];
        if (value < min) {
          min = value;
        }
      }
    }

    erodedFrame[y * width + x] = min;
  }
}

return erodedFrame;
}
```

Dilate:

```
function dilationFilter(frame, width, height) {

const dilatedFrame = new Uint8ClampedArray(frame.length);

for (let y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {
  for (let x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
    let max = 0;

    for (let j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
      for (let i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        const value = frame[(y + j) * width + (x + i)];
        if (value > max) {
          max = value;
        }
      }
    }

    dilatedFrame[y * width + x] = max;
  }
}

return dilatedFrame;
}
```

frame - Uint8ClampedArray to filter, returns filtered Uint8ClampedArray

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general way to compose a stack of SVG filters and apply it directly on a canvas:

```js
const DILATION_DISTANCE = 4;

const DILATION_SVG_FILTER_NAME = 'dilation';
const DILATION_SVG = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="${DILATION_SVG_FILTER_NAME}">
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="${DILATION_DISTANCE}" />
  </filter>
</svg>`;
const DILATION_SVG_URL = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(DILATION_SVG)}`;
const DILATION_CTX_FILTER = `url(${DILATION_SVG_URL}#${DILATION_SVG_FILTER_NAME})`;

// ...

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.filter = DILATION_CTX_FILTER;

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

1. Using a `data:` URL to compose the SVG instead of fetching it from elsewhere. You don't necessarily have to base-64 encode it via `btoa()`. `encodeURIComponent()` would also do.
2. You need to apply the filter on the rendering context *before* drawing the image.

In the OP's particular case, you can include a `<feColorMatrix>` filter before `<feMorphology>` to turn the image into grayscale first:

```
 <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
```

Assuming you're starting off with an `ImageData`, you'd need to put that on an off-screen canvas first and then the draw this canvas on your target canvas:

```js
const ofsCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(imageData.width, imageData.height);
const ofsCtx = ofsCanvas.getContext('2d');
ofsCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

ctx.filter = DILATION_CTX_FILTER;
ctx.drawImage(ofsCanvas, 0, 0); // You can draw a canvas on a canvas
```

You can also create the offscreen canvas using a DOM canvas, if browser support is an issue:

```js
const ofsCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
ofsCanvas.width = imageData.width;
ofsCanvas.height = imageData.height;
```

When done with all this, grab the dilated image's ImageData with:

```js
const dilatedImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```